Could you guide me on how to read tags with the Impinj M730 chip using the Zebra Android SDK?
We have developed an Android application using the Zebra RFID Reader SDK(https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/software/developer-tools/rfid-sdk-for-android.html) to read RFID tags with the Zebra 8500 handheld terminal. We were able to read NXP Ucode9 tags without any issues using our android application. However, we encountered difficulties reading Impinj M730 tags. It's worth noting that we could read tags with both chips using Zebra's proprietary application, '123RFID Mobile.' What am I missing? Thank you in advance for your assistance.
This is my Antenna config

private void setAntennaPower(int power) {
    Log.d(TAG, "setAntennaPower " + power);
    try {
        // set antenna configurations
        Antennas.AntennaRfConfig config = reader.Config.Antennas.getAntennaRfConfig(1);
        config.setTransmitPowerIndex(power);
        config.setrfModeTableIndex(0);
        config.setTari(0);
        reader.Config.Antennas.setAntennaRfConfig(1, config);
    } catch (InvalidUsageException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (OperationFailureException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


Have you thought about asking Zebra this? Maybe M730 tags are not supported by their SDK?

yes we asked. They said it is supported
